# Giving Error when try to insert CDR using mod_cdr_mongodb in freeswitch

Tags: mongodb, voip, freeswitch

I am trying to insert CDR into MongoDB using **mod_cdr_mongodb**. Without setting the username and password, I am able to load the **mod_cdr_mongodb** module and insert CDR after a hangup call into the MongoDB collection. However, when I set the username and password and try to load the **mod_cdr_mongodb** module, I get an authentication failed error.

```
2023-05-10 04:39:42.328309 78.30% [ERR] mod_cdr_mongodb.c:123 mongo_cmd_authenticate: authentication failed

2023-05-10 04:39:42.328309 78.30% [CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1755 Error Loading module /usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_cdr_mongodb.so
```

However, I am able to connect to MongoDB with the same username and password in the terminal and manually insert a query. But when using the FreeSWITCH module mod_cdr_mongodb, it gives an authentication error.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

I have configured the conf file as follows:

```
<configuration name="cdr_mongodb.conf" description="MongoDB CDR logger">
  <settings>
    <param name="host" value="127.0.0.1"/>
    <param name="port" value="27017"/>
    <param name="namespace" value="DB.cdrs"/>
    <param name="username" value="MONGO_USERNAME"/>
    <param name="password" value="MONGO_PASSWORD"/>
    <param name="log-b-leg" value="false"/>
  </settings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your mongo credentials are wrong. Where your conf file says `MONGO_USERNAME` and `MONGO_PASSWORD` do you have an actual, valid Mongo username and password? have you tested those credentials with another mongo client?

Comment: Yes credential are correct, using same details I'm able to connect in my python script.